# Is there need of a comma after however in this sentence? And how can I improve the structure of this sentence?

Tags: commas, syntactic-analysis, however-placement

According to Klaudia, birds disperse as an immediate response to flood, however they assemble back on the wetland, as the flooded areas elsewhere decline in extent.

Answer (score 1):

*According to Klaudia, birds disperse as an immediate response to flood, however they assemble back on the wetland, as the flooded areas elsewhere decline in extent.*

Yes Adrian, you need a comma after "however". However, you need to add a semicolon after "flood" as your sentence contains two independent clauses that relate to each other. Look at this:

*According to Klaudia, birds disperse as an immediate response to flood; however, they assemble back on the wetland as the flooded areas elsewhere decline in extent.*

The semicolon links "birds disperse as an immediate response to flood" to "however, they assemble back on the wetland as the flooded areas elsewhere decline in extent." It acts as a conjunction and works better for reader comprehension than two separate sentences would.

Notice I deleted the comma after "assemble back on the wetland" because "as the flooded areas decline in extent" is an adverbial phrase telling us *when* the birds assemble back on the mainland, and you usually don't use commas before adverbials.

Hope this cleared this up for you!